# Access VBA is not running my XML transformation

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, vba

I've got an access database that exports data to an XML document and then transforms it using an XSLT file. It was working fine up until a few minutes ago when all of a sudden, it no longer transforms the XML, but it still does the first export.

Here is my VBA code;

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command364_Click()
    Dim objAD As AdditionalData

    Set objAD = Application.CreateAdditionalData

    With objAD
        .Add "master_version"
        .Add "press_section"
        .Add "version"
        .Add "task_info_press_section"
        .Add "task_info_post_press"
        .Add "post_press_version"
    End With

    Application.ExportXML acExportQuery, "order", _
    "C:\Users\James Brace\Documents\Technique Access Stuff\Exports\ExportPreXSLT.xml", _
    WhereCondition:="[ORDERPK] = " & [Forms]![frmMAINENTRY]![ORDERPK], _
    AdditionalData:=objAD

    Application.TransformXML "C:\Users\James Brace\Documents\Technique Access Stuff\Exports\ExportPreXSLT.xml", _
                         "C:\Users\James Brace\Documents\Technique Access Stuff\Exports\XSLT Template.xsl", _
                         "C:\Users\James Brace\Documents\Technique Access Stuff\Exports\ExportTransformed.xml"

End Sub
```

Nothing has changed in this code, so I can't figure out why all of a sudden it's stopped working. It's definitely firing the whole event, as I've tested it with MsgBox lines before and after the TransformXML command. Here is the XSLT I'm using;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <!-- removes specified nodes from all elements -->

   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>

   <!-- Creates attributes against the ORDER element -->
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="dataroot">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::master_version)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | Replace"/>

   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="order">
       <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../master_version"/>
       </order>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="press_section">
       <press_section>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../task_info_press_section"/>
       </press_section>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="../task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT; I've also tried decompiling and then compiling the code, and also a Compact & Repair on the database, but this hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it was an error in the XSLT. I couldn't find the error, but re-writing the code from scratch did the job.

Comment: Why not delete this altogether, then? It 's not going to help anyone else.